# XML Schema: keyref to hierarchically lower element

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, key, keyref

My XML structure is the following:

```
ROOT
   |_ SetOfBandC (*)
   |               |_ SetOfB (1)
   |               |           |_ ElementB (*)
   |               |           |_ ElementB__Key 
   |               |_ SetOfC (1)
   |                           |_ ElementC (*)
   |                           |_ ElementC__Key 
   |_ ElementD (*)
   |
   |_ SetOfBandC__Key
   |_ ElementD__Key
   |
   |_ ElementD->SetOfBandC__Keyref
   |_ ElementD->ElementB__Keyref
```

In this structure I can have multiple `SetOfBandC` as well as multiple `ElementB` and `ElementC`, but only 1 `SetofB` and `SetOfC` for each `SetOfBandC`.

The problem is that `ElementD` has a keyref referencing a particular `SetOfBandC` and another one referencing a `ElementB` of that set, but the XML Validator when checking for the `ElementD->ElementB__Keyref`'s validity it only searches in the *last* `SetOfBandC`, and not in all of them or, better, in the one referenced by `ElementD->SetOfBandC__Keyref`. 
So when `ElementD->ElementB__Keyref` references an `ElementB` which is not in the last `SetOfBandC`, validation won't work.

Here is my `ElementD->ElementB__Keyref`:

```
<xs:keyref name="ElementD->ElementB__Keyref" refer="tns:ElementB__Key ">
    <xs:selector xpath="tns:ElementD" />
    <xs:field xpath="@elementD_ref" />
</xs:keyref>
```

And my `ElementB__Key`:

```
<xs:key name="ElementB__Key">
    <xs:selector xpath="tns:ElementB" />
    <xs:field xpath="@elemB_name" />
</xs:key>
```

Where tns is my target namespace. What am I missing?

PS: names in my code are different and there are not `->` in them.

Comment: Post the whole schema

Comment: @Sprotty I would have preferred not to do that but I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the scope of the keys.

As far as I understand, a node is globally identified not only by its *node name*, but also by the *name of the nffg* is belongs to. This is thus globally a compound key: a policy refers to a node with an nffg name as well as a node name. In the current schema, the `keyRef`s in policies however only refer to these two keys independently from each other, so XML Schema doesn't know that they go together.

Maybe a way out would be to use globally unique node names made of prefixing the node key with the nffg key, like `Nffg1-Node1`, and to use this instead as a single keyref in the policy. If you also want to make sure that a link refers to a source and destination node *within the same nffg*, you may need two key definitions for `node`: one global for the policy `keyRef`s (under `allNffgsAndPolicies`), one local to an nffg (under `nffg`) for the link `keyRef`s.

A slightly different alternative is to repeat the `nffgName` attribute in nodes, and use this together with the unchanged `nodeName` attribute as a global compound key for nodes -- by using two `xs:field` elements in the key -- that you can use in policies. You should be able to ensure that a node's local `nffgname` attribute matches that of the parent nffg with `key`s and `keyRef`s as well.

**Bonus question**: it still does not explain why, with the original instance and schema, `Node3` is rejected but other values are accepted. I would have expected the error to be thrown on a value present on both subtrees. In the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#sec-sic-key), conflicting keys across children are removed from the node table, however in this case a key like `Node2` would be conflicting as it is on both subtrees, but not `Node3` as it only appears in the first subtree. The contrary happens here though and only the last child's node table seems to be considered for inclusion in the top-level node table.

Comment: Thanks for the nice ideas. Sadly I can't modify much of the schema since it is already used by xml files and even by some applications, it would be better to modify just the key/keyrefs in order to make the problematic ones, `srcNodeRef` and `destNodeRef`, work.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, RVKS. I have posted another answer that should fulfil this additional constraint.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use XML Schema 1.1, the following should work with no modification of XML documents or of the schema structure itself.

- Remove both `keyRef`s for `tns:policy`
- Instead, use an assertion in the complex type for `allNffgsAndPolicies`:

  ```
  <xs:element name="allNffgsAndPolicies">
      <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
              <!-- same content as in original schema -->
          </xs:sequence>  
          <xs:assert test="every $i in tns:policy satisfies $i/@srcNode = tns:nffg/tns:nodes/tns:node/@nodeName and $i/@destNode = tns:nffg/tns:nodes/tns:node/@nodeName"/>
      </xs:complexType>
      <!-- other keys and keyRefs, only keep the first three -->
  </xs:element>
  ```

I could test this successfully in oXygen: it validates the original document, and fails validation if using unexisting source or destination node names.

To activate XML Schema 1.1, add these attributes in the `xs:schema` element:

```
xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"
```

To go the extra mile: if on top of that, you also want to make sure that the node name exists within the nffg referenced by the policy with `nffgRef`, you can fine-tune the assertion:

```
<xs:assert test="
  every $i in tns:policy satisfies
  $i/@srcNode = tns:nffg[@nffgName eq $i/@nffgRef]/tns:nodes/tns:node/@nodeName
  and
  $i/@destNode = tns:nffg[@nffgName eq $i/@nffgRef]/tns:nodes/tns:node/@nodeName"/>
```

Comment: Sadly I cannot use XML Schema 1.1. But thank you again for your great support! Do you think that there is no way of doing that with `keyref`s? Even your first solution, the one which searches for the node in all the Nffgs and not in the pointed one, would be ok.